# No install option displayed when installing gnuplot using brew

Tags: homebrew, gnuplot

I want to install gnuplot with options like --with-aquaterm, --wx ..., but when I type `brew options gnuplot` before installation, terminal displays nothing. When I installed gnuplot before, there was several options available. How can I fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Homebrew has removed all options:

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/31510